# VB.net Create controls at runtime using class?

Tags: vb.net, controls, runtime

Hi I am looking to create controls at run time but with a bit more complexity:

I have collection of controls that I want to duplicate at runtime and then access, say:

- 2 text boxes
- 2 labels
- 1 Button

What is the best way of grouping them for easy access? Can I create a class that makes these items and then I just make a new class every time I want make a new set of controls?

Comment: WebForms, WinForms, MVC...?

Comment: You can use a `UserControl`.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is designing an UserControl and create it at runtime all the times you need.

Designing an UserControl allows you to include that textboxes, labels, button and group them like you want.

Check this at MSDN:

[Creating a Windows Form User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx)